# i used google api translate but it return null

Tags: android, google-translator-toolkit

this is the code i want to translate text but **without** using http i want it to translate direct i see this tutorial but it return null i was try to change in the RETURN  of each function 
and i already import google-api-translate-java-0.95.jar

Import that JAR file to android buid Path (Right-click *Project* -> *Properties* -> *Java Build Path* -> *Libraries* -> *Add External JARS*.)
please help me 
thanx in advance

```
 main.xml:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

The JAVA file

Translator.java:

```
    public class Translator extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String translatedText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    Translate t = new Translate();
     public String execute(String arg0, Language arg1, Language arg2)
            throws GoogleAPIException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null  ;
    }

    public String[] execute(String[] arg0, Language arg1, Language arg2)
            throws GoogleAPIException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String[] execute(String arg0, Language arg1, Language[] arg2)
            throws GoogleAPIException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String[] execute(String[] arg0, Language[] arg1, Language[] arg2)
            throws GoogleAPIException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }};

    try {
      translatedText = t.execute("Bonjour le monde", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);


    } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
     }


    Toast.makeText(this, translatedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    tv.setText(translatedText);

    setContentView(tv);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, Google Translate API requires http connection